# Selenium Safari "Unknown command"

Tags: java, selenium, safari

I'm working on Safari Browser and i got a problem.

```
"Unknown command: {"id":"5qhlf8uni92m","name":"mouseMoveTo","parameters":{"yoffset":25,"xoffset":10}}
```

> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

How can i deal with this ?

**NOTE:** In my scenario, *f book* shows a notification pop-up and i can't select any element because when pop-up showed up, black screen appeared and i have to click anywhere to enable elements. That's why i used this code;

```
WebElement knownElement = null; 
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(knownElement, 10, 25).click().build().perform();
```

In my opinion, it cause this problem. How can i change this code to fit in Safari ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Refer this link : https://ynot408.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/drag-and-drop-using-selenium-webdriver/

OR : 

        public boolean onMouseOver(WebElement element){
            boolean result = false;
            try{
                String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){
                var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover',
    true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);
} else if(document.createEventObject){
 arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript(mouseOverScript, element);
                result = true;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }
```